# Prevent Apple Watch face from showing when Do Not Disturb on

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, watchos, do-not-disturb

When Do Not Disturb is on, my Apple Watch still shows the watch face when I turn my wrist. This is a pain at night, because every time I move, I get a bright light shining from the Watch.

When Do Not Disturb is on, I only want the watch to be activated when I press the crown. Is this possible?

Comment: Simplest answer - don't sleep with your watch on. This has been the general advice since the advent of the clockwork watch.

Comment: If Do Not Disturb is on, there isn't a reason the watch should be worn to bed as mentioned above by @Tetsujin .

Comment: I use it as an alarm to wake me up

Comment: It's also helpful for reading your resting heart rate, or using apps that track your sleep.

Answer (score 4):

In watchOS 3.2, Apple added **Theater Mode**, accessed by swiping up from the Watch Face and tapping the bottom-left icon.

[image: Theater Mode]

**Theater Mode** silences the WATCH and prevents the screen from lighting up on wrist-raise or when receiving notifications. Taptic feedback will still be triggered.

You can combine **Theater Mode** and **Do Not Disturb** to silence Taptic feedback, as well. Alarms will still ring as normal.

Comment: Just an FYI, the  character doesn't display correctly on any non-Apple device

Answer (score 2):

In WatchOS 7 Apple introduced the Sleep mode natively: https://support.apple.com/fi-fi/guide/watch/apd830528336/watchos .

The sleep mode differs from Theater by a few ways:

- Tapping does wake the screen now
- Opt-in sleep tracking
- Digital and more dimmed clock

Answer (score 1):

Yes. **Theater mode** is the perfect option for it.

It silences your Apple Watch's screen, leaving the display off unless you intentionally tap the screen or press one of the watch's buttons.

Theater Mode: On will display at the top of the screen in Control Center. On your watch face, you'll also see a theater mask in the top center of the screen to indicate that you currently have Theater Mode activated.

For more info refer this link.

https://www.imore.com/how-to-use-theater-mode-apple-watch